# Sort arrays in alphabetical order and numeric order

Tags: python

```
import csv
num_rows = 0

f_obj = open("Class1.csv", encoding='utf-8-sig')
f = f_obj.read()

for row in open("Class1.csv", encoding='utf-8-sig'):
  num_rows = num_rows + 1

for i in range(1,num_rows):
  f_values = (f.split('\n')[i]).split(",")
  print(f_values)
  #Output:
  
  #['ALEX', '0', '0', '0']
  #['DAVID', '10', '11', '10']
  #['Ben', '10', '10', '10']

sortType = input("1) Sort by Alphabetical Order" "\n" "2) Sort by Total Score" "\n")
if sortType == 1:
  #I want it to output output:
  
  #['ALEX', '0', '0', '0']
  #['Ben', '10', '11', '10']
  #['DAVID', '10', '11', '11']
elif sortType == 2:
  #I want it to output:
  
  #['DAVID', '10', '11', '11']
  #['Ben', '10', '11', '10']
  #['ALEX', '0', '0', '0']
```

So I have made the code above which fetches data from a .csv file and prints it out. I want to be able to print out the data in alphabetical and numerical order but I am not sure how to go about swapping them around. This is just a sample of data, the real list is about 100 lines long and I want to make sure all of them are sorted correctly in order.
[image]

Comment: as a side note, *learn pandas* if you are going to be working with csvs a lot

Comment: what do you mean by ```Total Score``` ?

Comment: @khaledkoubaa  So the 3 numbers added together, for example [David10+11+11=32], [Ben,10+11+10=31]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that 'Class1.csv' has no header and no special column for row names, and consists of rows separated by **newline** with values separated by **comma**, and has no empty values, and everything else, as I hope it is. Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('Class1.csv',header=None)
```

Next... to sort alphabetically:

```
df=df.sort_values(0) #0 is the column with names
#uncomment the following line to create a new **csv** file:
#df.to_csv('Class_sorted_alpha.csv',header=False,index=False)
```

Next... to sort numerically:

```
#create a column with total score
#(df.loc[:,1:] is the numerical part of the column):
df=df.assign(total=df.loc[:,1:].sum(axis=1))
#sort by the 'total' column:
df=df.sort_values('total',ascending=False)
#delete the unnecessary "total" column:
del df['total']
#uncomment the following line to create a new **csv** file:
#df.to_csv('Class_sorted_numerically.csv',header=False,index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a custom sorting function to accomplish this:

```
def getname(item):
    return item[0]

def sortByName(item1, item2):
    if getname(item1) < getname(item2):
        return -1
    elif getname(item1) > name(item2):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

# populate a "super" list which contains all of your sub lists
mlist = []
for i in range(1,num_rows):
    f_values = (f.split('\n')[i]).split(",")
    mlist.append(f_values)

# then sort it out
mlist.sort(key=sortByName)
mlist.sort(key=sortByName, reverse=True)
```

Edit:

By the way, you can simplify the file reading to this:

```
# ...

with open("", "r") as f:
    content = f.readlines()

for line in content:
    mlist.append(l.split(","))

print("total rows: {}".format(len(mlist)))

# ...
```

Comment: this is how you do it... in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Start by writing functions that extract a sorting key from a row:

```
def by_name(row):
   return row[0]

def by_total_score(row):
   return sum(int(x) for x in row[1:])
```

In the sorting part, simply provide one of these as the `key` argument to `sort`:

```
 if sort_type == 1:
   rows.sort(key=by_name)
 if sort_type == 2:
   rows.sort(key=by_total_score)
```

Good luck!

Comment: "NameError: name 'rows' is not defined."

Comment: @niub: what's this?

Comment: I tried to do your code and I keep getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use default python `sort` method:

You need to specify the column you want to use as your base to sort inside the `x[i]` like below:

```
sortType = input("1) Sort by Alphabetical Order" "\n" "2) Sort by Total Score" "\n")
if sortType == 1:
    f_values.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
elif sortType == 2:
    f_values.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```